# How can I hide or remove a div class of a special page powered by MediaWIki?

Tags: php, html, css, mediawiki

I am trying to remove the circled section [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7o58.png):

The picture is a special page powered by MediaWiki and I cannot edit it in the same way as normal wiki pages. Instead, I am able to access its php file, and have found a function I believe to be responsible for setting up the page:

```
/**
 * Sets up everything for the HTML output page including styles, javascript,
 * page title, etc.
 *
 * @param string $term
 */
protected function setupPage( $term ) {
    $out = $this->getOutput();

    $this->setHeaders();
    $this->outputHeader();
    $out->allowClickjacking();
    $this->addHelpLink( 'Help:Searching' );

    if ( strval( $term ) !== '' ) {
        $out->setPageTitle( $this->msg( 'searchresults' ) );
        $out->setHTMLTitle( $this->msg( 'pagetitle' )
            ->plaintextParams( $this->msg( 'searchresults-title' )->plaintextParams( $term )->text() )
            ->inContentLanguage()->text()
        );
    }

    $out->addJsConfigVars( [ 'searchTerm' => $term ] );

    $out->addModules( 'mediawiki.special.search' );
    $out->addModuleStyles( [
        'mediawiki.special', 'mediawiki.special.search.styles', 'mediawiki.ui', 'mediawiki.ui.button',
        'mediawiki.ui.input', 'mediawiki.widgets.SearchInputWidget.styles',
    ] );

}
```

However, I am not sure of what changes I can make to hide/remove the search bar. I was hoping to find a piece of HTML code where I can edit, but I was not able to find it.

Comment: Why would you want to remove the search bar from the search page? What point would that page have after that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to hide elements is to use jquery. More Information see [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Adding_JavaScript_to_Wiki_Pages)